# How to "link" Arrays in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wonder how I can create a virtual Link between Arrays or get an Master and Slave Arrays?

I use often "Blocks" of Arrays to store all kind of Informations from an event. Because The
information that belongs together have all the same ID, it's easy to call them. BUT if I will sort one of them, the chaos would be perfect.

I try to explain it with an Example:
Assume every time there is an Up Candle we store its Values and other Informations like high, low, open, close, time, ....
If I want to see the Informations from the third stored Candle, I simply use array.get(array , 2) and get from all arrays the Information who belongs to it.

But if I now want to find the Highes High Value, I have to start a loop and this cost a lot of time. It's faster to simply sort the array and use array.get(array, 0). So it will be automatically the Highes Value. But this effect a massive Chaos because all the other Arrays got not sorted and all Informations are cluttered.

How can I achieve that when the "High" Value switched from id position 5 to 0, also the other arrays id`s switch from 5 to 0?

Comment: Could you be so glad and provide feedback to the answers? That's how Stackoverflow lives

Answer (score 0):

Sorting will involve some looping anyways so if you go over the Array with a loop, it won't be that slow.

But what you want is `array.sort_indices`. It will return an index Array which will contain index values, referencing to the original Array. If you use these values as indices on the original array, you will access the original Array in the sorted order. And you can access the other Arrays with this same index-array.

Check the Pinescript manual on this method: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array.sort_indices

Answer (score 0):

You could use maps instead of arrays. Store the bar_index as key and the price as value. As soon as you sort your high array, you can sort the other ones according to the keys of the high array. Consider that a map in Pine Script keep the keys in the order you added them. It not a KeySet like you may know from other languages.

If you then create a type definition around everything you have what you need and maybe wanna put this into a library.

```
export type MasterSlaveOhlcs
    map<int, float> opens  = na
    map<int, float> highs  = na
    map<int, float> lows   = na
    map<int, float> closes = na

createMasterSlaveOhlcs() =>
    MasterSlaveOhlcs.new(map<int, float>.new(), map<int, float>.new(), map<int, float>.new(), map<int, float>.new())

sortByKeyDesc(map<int, float> a) =>
    map<int, float> result
    // Just sort it
    result

sortByKeyAccording(map<int, float> toSort, map<int, float> reference) =>
    map<int, float> result
    // Add entries from toSort to result according key order from reference
    result

export sortHighDesc(MasterSlaveOhlcs ohlcs) =>
    MasterSlaveOhlcs result = createMasterSlaveOhlcs()
    result.highs  := sortByKeyDesc(ohlcs.highs)
    result.opens  := sortByKeyAccording(ohlcs.opens, result.highs)
    result.lows   := sortByKeyAccording(ohlcs.lows, result.highs)
    result.closes := sortByKeyAccording(ohlcs.closes, result.highs)
    result
```